# Can not get output of Runtime.getRuntime().exec(python script);

Tags: java, python, shell, output, exec

I'm trying to write a output file of a python script using java exec, however I get no output.
I got the expected file however is empty.
I made a script do what I want.

```
#!/bin/bash/
cd /home/taste/work/AIR/air/
python configure -f .air_config
```

I have already tried to execute this script from the shell and I can get the output.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"bash","-c","sh 
./Configuration_Data/Scripts/"+cF.folderName+"/testConfigure.sh > 
configureOut.txt"});
```

This is the way I'm reading :

```
  String line ="";
  //Used to create output
  StringBuilder text  = new StringBuilder();
  BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new 
  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

  while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
    text.append(line+"\n");
    System.out.println(line);
  }
```

I would like to have output from my python file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you direct the script's output with `> configureOut.txt` to the file, there's simply nothing left to read from the input stream. If you really want the output in both the file and the input stream, you could change the above redirection to `| tee configureOut.txt`.

Comment: I already tried "| tee" however I got no output when I use exec to run my script, on the other hand when I run my script through shell I get output.

Comment: How did you try _"| tee"_ exactly, and on which operating system?

Comment: Where I have " > XXX" I have replaced with "| tee". I'm working at Linux Debian.

Comment: An `strace -fe execve` of your Java program could be enlightening.

Comment: Can you be more enlightening ? 
It's strange because it create the output file but with no content.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know the reason for the failure, hence I suggested a way to gather further information. But now at least it's clear that, since the input stream as well as the output file is empty, the script execution generates *no* output.